# Checking the possibility to make a call

Tags: android

I'd to check whether it's possible to make a normal call (not only emergency call) and if it is then get the number of a sim card by what it is possible to do (including the case when it is a dual sim card - get the active number). And I also want to check whether  or not the phone is in roaming. So overall there might be 3 cases:

1. It is not possible to make a normal call - the phone is in roaming and **there is no operator** which supports its "home" operator or the phone is just unavailable due to its location (in a subway, for example).
2. It is possible to make a call and the phone is in roaming
3. It is possible to make a call and the phone is not in roaming, it is in its home country.

Is this all possible and if yes then how? The general instructions are ok.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html).
There are methods to check whether you are roaming,cell info and more data.
You can use this information to achieve what you are trying to do.